# What if I must override a non-virtual member function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, dynamic-binding

Say we have a library which provides a class

```
struct Base { int foo() { return 42; } };
```

**I cannot change that class.**
99% of the people never want to override `foo`, hence it has not been made virtual by the library designers.
But I need to override it:

```
struct MyClass : Base { int foo() { return 73; } };
```

Even worse, the library has interfaces accepting pointers to `Base`.
I want to plug in `MyClass`, but of course, since `foo` is not virtual, the code behind the interface always calls `Base::foo`. **I want it to call `MyClass::foo`.**

**What can I do about it?** Is there a common pattern to make `Base::foo` appear to be virtual?

<sub>In reality, `Base::foo` is `QAbstractProxyModel::sourceModel`.
I'm implementing a `ProxyChain`, to abstract many proxy models to a single one.
`QAbstractProxyModel::setSourceModel` is virtual, but `QAbstractProxyModel::sourceModel` isn't and that makes a lot of trouble.</sub>

```
void ProxyChain::setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* source_model)
{
  for (auto* proxy : m_proxies) {
    proxy->setSourceModel(source_model);
    source_model = proxy;
  }
  QIdentityProxyModel::setSourceModel(source_model);
}

QAbstractItemModel* ProxyChain::sourceModel() const
{
  return m_proxies.front()->sourceModel();
}
```

Comment: _"I cannot change that class."_ Well, you're buggered then, because it has no public members and thus you cannot actually do anything with it.

Comment: Given the constraints you've imposed, it's not possible. However, I also think that this is probably an XY problem. It's not your job to write unit tests for the library, after all.

Comment: Nobody mentioned unit tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do about it?

Nothing.

This is why guidelines tell us to use `virtual` if we want other people to be able to "pretend" that their classes are versions of our classes.

The author of `Base` did not do that, so you do not have that power.

That's it.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the answer, though I had hoped for better news :/

Comment: It _is_ good news! Well, in general, anyway. Next week you'll be asking how to stop people from overriding your classes without consent so that you can guarantee consistent behaviours inside your library ;) For now you're going to have to use the library as intended. Or fork it, or make a feature request to its authors, or both.

Answer (score 4):

> What can I do about it?

Nothing. If a member function is non-`virtual`, then it is non-`virtual`. This means that any code, anywhere in the code base, which takes a `Base` pointer or reference who calls `base->foo` will be calling exactly and only `Base::foo`. This call is statically (compile-time) bound to the function it calls.

You cannot reach into someone else's code and *make* them use dynamic binding. If they didn't choose to participate in dynamic binding, then you can't make them. You can create your own derived class and write your own version of `foo` which hides the base class version. But this will not affect the behavior of any code which gets a pointer/reference to `Base`.

In your specific case, your best bet will be to make sure to call the base class `setSourceModel` with the object that you want `sourceModel` to return any time something changes which changes what `sourceModel` should return.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the last paragraph. I am forced to set the source model to the last item of the `m_proxies`-vector, however, `sourceModel` must return the first item. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have to admit I didn't quite grok that either

Comment: @pasbi: "*I am forced to set the source model to the last item of the m_proxies-vector*" I don't know the objects you're working with, but nothing in the apparent API of them *forces* you to set the source model to the last item. You can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: Sure, I could do that. But that would break the internals of `QIdentityProxyModel` (and `QAbstractProxyModel`, respectively). You're right, it's not about API but about implementation detail of the library classes. But unfortunately that's the way it is.